# Cassandra data model with obsolete data removal possibility

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, data-modeling, cql3, cassandra-2.0

I'm new to cassandra and would like to ask what would be correct model design pattern for such tasks.
I would like to model data with future removal possibility.

I have 100,000,000 records per day of this structure:

- transaction_id <- this is unique
- transaction_time
- transaction_type
- user_name
- ... some other information

I will need to fetch data by user_name (I have about 5,000,000 users).
Also I will need to find transaction details by its id.
All the data will be irrelevant after say about 30 days, so need to find a way to delete outdated rows.

As much I have found, TTL-s expire column values, not rows.
So far I came across with this model, and as I understand it will imply really wide rows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_transactions (
  transaction_date timestamp,    //date part of transactiom
  user_name text,
  transaction_id text,
  transaction_time timestamp,    //original transaction time
  transaction_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((transaction_date, user_name), transaction_id)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_user_transactions_uname ON USER_TRANSACTIONS(user_name);
CREATE INDEX idx_user_transactions_tid ON USER_TRANSACTIONS(transaction_id);
```

but this model does not allow deletions by transaction_date.
this also builds indexes with high cardinality, what cassandra docs strongly discourages

So what will be the correct model for this task?

**EDIT:**

Ugly workaround I came with so far is to create single table per date partition. Mind you, I call this workaround and not a solution. I'm still looking for right data model

```
CREATE TABLE user_transactions_YYYYMMDD (
  user_name text,
  transaction_id text,
  transaction_time timestamp, 
  transaction_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_name)
);
```

YYYYMMDD is date part of transaction. we can create similar table with transaction_id for transaction lookup. obsolete tables can be dropped or truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should denormalized your data model. For example to query by user_name you can use a cf like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_transactions (
  transaction_date timestamp,    //date part of transactiom
  user_name text,
  transaction_id text,
  transaction_time timestamp,    //original transaction time
  transaction_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_name, transaction_id)
);
```

So you can query using the partition key directly like this:

SELECT * FROM user_transactions WHERE user_name = 'USER_NAME';

And for the id you can use a cf like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_transactions (
  transaction_date timestamp,    //date part of transactiom
  user_name text,
  transaction_id text,
  transaction_time timestamp,    //original transaction time
  transaction_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);
```

so the query could be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_transactions WHERE transaction_id = 'ID';
```

By this way you dont need indexes.

About the TTL, maybe you could programatically ensure that you update all the columns in the row at the same time (same cql sentence).

Comment: yes but these models does not allow me to delete data using DELETE statement specifying transaction date. this is the reason why I'm trying to move transaction date into partition key.
any other ways to delete old data?

Comment: forgot to mention that data written in tables are immutable and I never need to modify it.

Comment: In that case you can create an index on transaction_date, query for the list of transaction_id based on that date and use the list to delete by transaction_id.

Comment: you mean run 100,000,000 individual DELETE-s?
really really doubt if cassandra can handle this.

Comment: One of the objectives of cassandra is achieve hight throughput. If cassandra can handle this depends on the cluster your are using but not because of cassandra itself. The other solution is use the TTL as I mention in the last line of the solution, but you have to update all the columns at the same time, so all the columns are deleted at the same time. Another thing you have to consider is the tombstones, maybe you should reduce the gc_grace_seconds parameter in the cf to avoid generate a lot of tombstones after the delete process.

Comment: Maybe I understand it wrong, but TTL-s expire values, not columns and rows, so after it expires I will be left with some kind of "ghost" partition keys, without values.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Also do delete this amount of data in reasonible time and not eventually in several hours, one should not need big cluster to do this. I believe correct design pattern exist for such tasks and I'm asking for that.

Comment: Why you assume the delete would take several hours?

Comment: 100,000,000 individual delete queries should not complete in seconds.
data models you posted would work fine for data  searching, but will struggle when deleting outdated data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer will be a little useful.

I would have done so:

```
CREATE TABLE user_transactions (
  date timestamp,
  user_name text,
  id text,
  type int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_user_transactions_uname ON user_transactions (user_name);
```

No need in 'transaction_time timestamp', because this time will be set by Cassandra to each column, and can be fetched by WRITETIME(column name) function. Because you write all the columns simultaneously, then you can call this function on any column.

```
INSERT INTO user_transactions ... USING TTL 86400;
```

will expire all columns simultaneously. So do not worry about deleting rows. See here: [Expiring columns](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_t.html).

But as far as I know, you can not delete an entire row - key column still remains, and in the other columns will be written NULL. 
If you want to delete the rows manually, or just want to have an estimate of rows to be deleted by a TTL, then I recommend driver Astyanax: [AllRowsReader All rows query](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/AllRowsReader-All-rows-query).

And indeed as a driver to work with Cassandra I recommend you use Astyanax.

Comment: Dmitry, it does not really matters here, but transaction_time not always matches write_date.

Comment: Are you sure that the entire row isn't removed? Cause i also did think that was true (read it everywhere), but items with a ttl of 1 day do not appear anymore when i do a select * query after for example 1 or 2 days. That did surprise me ;)

Comment: no I'm not sure about it. it is what I have read in docs and blogs and forums. have you tried to look what underlying data looks from CLI and not CQLSH? because CQL might mask & hide what is really going on (as is with composite & compound keys).

Comment: Indeed, it seems that the cassandra driver and cqlsh hides them, when i execute "list keyspace" with cassandra-cli the deleted items still show the RowKey of deleted rows. Will dive a bit deeper in cassandra-cli stuff.

Comment: Yep. Was expecting that answer.